# can I disable CSS and images in selenium with Edge driver?

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have been googling on how to disable image and css on selenium but all I found was for firefox and chrome, is there anyway to disable it on edge?

btw I'm using python selenium

Comment: It's funny. I did a little googling for this as well, and it is difficult to find out all the capabilities for the EdgeDriver.

Comment: Can you please inform us whether you are using the MS Edge legacy version or you are using the MS Edge Chromium browser? Also, let us know about the exact version of the browser. If you had tested any code then you can also post it. We will try to check it and provide suggestions for it. Thanks for your understanding.